# Опять Word сетует, что предложение не согласовано

Tags: грамотная-речь

Упитанный круглолицый мужчина по-своему интерпретировал мое пожелание, сообщив, что в хостелах обычно живут прибывшие на заработки, потом набрал на мобильном телефоне номер, найденный в каком-то журнале напарницей и, подождав пару секунд, отрицательно покачал головой: мол, никто не поднимает трубку.

Answer (score 1):

Системе не нравится слово ***прибывшие***, она считает, что это, возможно, прилагательное. Проверить можно так: живут **люди**, прибывшие...

Comment: Т. е. все в порядке?

Comment: Я скопировала ваше предложение : Упитанный круглолицый мужчина по-своему интерпретировал  мое пожелание, сообщив, что в хостелах обычно живут ЛЮДИ, прибывшие на заработки, потом набрал на мобильном телефоне номер, найденный в каком-то журнале напарницей и, подождав пару секунд, отрицательно покачал головой. Раньше текст был подчеркнут, а в таком виде нет. Думаю, что Word не может четко определить вид прилагательного - субстантивированное или обычное.